# Highlight a bar in sns barplot which value exceeded the total value

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to highlight bars that have values exceeded the total value.

```
import pandas as pd

m_data = {
    "total": [30, 25, 25, 5, 15],
    "current": [20, 15, 15, 10, 15],
    "abbrev": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
}
m = pd.DataFrame(m_data)

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))


# Plot the total crashes
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="total", y="abbrev", data=m_data,
            label="test1", color="b")

# Plot the crashes where alcohol was involved
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="current", y="abbrev", data=m_data,
            label="test", color="b")

# Add a legend and informative axis label
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 35), ylabel="",
       xlabel="values")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

for i in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(i,)
```

My output:

[Current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APYtn.png)

My expected:

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAbk9.png)

I am wondering whether is there a way to just show a highlight part with different color for that exceeded value so that its easy to see that the bar is exceeded.

Comment: Is there anyone could assist me with this? Please

Answer (score 0):

You could plot the bars in 4 steps:

- first the "totals"
- then the "alcohol involved"
- for the bars that have excess:

  - plot them using the value of the "alcohol involved" ones, in a
    special color, optionally with hatching
  - erase part of them using the value of "total", but the color of the "alcohol involved" ones

The `order=` keyword ensures all bars are drawn at the correct position.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

m = pd.DataFrame({"total": [30, 25, 25, 5, 15],
                  "current": [20, 15, 15, 10, 15],
                  "abbrev": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]})

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))

y_order = m["abbrev"].values
# Plot the total crashes
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="total", y="abbrev", data=m,
            label="total", color="b", ax=ax)

# Plot the crashes where alcohol was involved
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="current", y="abbrev", data=m,
            label="alcohol involved", color="b", ax=ax)

m_excessed = m[m["current"] > m["total"]]
if len(m_excessed) > 0:
    # Plot the excess bars
    sns.set_color_codes("bright")
    sns.barplot(x="current", y="abbrev", data=m_excessed, order=y_order, hatch='//',
                label="excess", color="b", ax=ax)
    # Replot the total bars, to erase part of excess bars
    sns.set_color_codes("muted")
    sns.barplot(x="total", y="abbrev", data=m_excessed, order=y_order,
                  color="b", ax=ax)

# Add a legend and informative axis label
ax.legend(ncol=1, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 35), ylabel="",
       xlabel="values")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

for i in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(i)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot with part "erased"]